# Check if Raspivid service is running?

Tags: ssh, systemd, services, raspivid

I am creating a program the requires the following:

1. Check if raspivid is currently running.
2. Check if its running out of a services file.
3. if it is running out of a specific file, determine which services file that is.

is any of this possible? I have a preliminary understanding of Raspberry Pi so far.

Comment: Oddly enough this is not actually a Pi problem (see https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic number 6) and would sit better with the Linux Exchange here https://unix.stackexchange.com. They are best placed to answer as you are trying to find out about Linux commands / services BUT I would guess they will close till you have read up on ps/htop/top commands and how service files work.  Have a look https://linuxhint.com/systemd_unit_file_service/ for an intro to systems services.  Very odd answer (and here is different from the RPF site) but by the rules its a close from me. Sorry.

Comment: Ah understandable. Thanks for the feedback, I will look at these sources. Thank you.